# Delta function on calendar view is returning a duplicate key "id" in the response

Tags: rest, api, office365, microsoft-graph-api

I am using a delta function on the calendar view to track the changes. I am noticing that the response coming back from the query contains "id" key twice. 
This is the URI used to make the delta query:
String uri = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/calendars/" + this.calendarId + "/calendarView/delta?startDateTime="+startStr+"&endDateTime="+endStr;

The headers I am adding to the GET request are:
"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0"
"Accept": "application/json"
"Authorization":"Bearer "+ accessToken
"Prefer":"outlook.timezone=\"Eastern Standard Time\""

The response that I am getting back is (values truncated/modified for security reasons, but notice the duplicate "id" key):

```
{
"@odata.context": ...,
"@odata.nextLink": ...,
"value": [{
    "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.event",
    "@odata.etag": ...,
    "createdDateTime": "2017-09-29T13:42:30.2678102Z",
    "lastModifiedDateTime": "2017-09-29T13:42:30.7678196Z",
    "changeKey": ...,
    "categories": [],
    "originalStartTimeZone": "UTC",
    "originalEndTimeZone": "UTC",
    "iCalUId": "040000008200E00074C5B7101A82E008000000005644B0CB2839D301000000000000000010000000D82FB69E4CC6794B9EF363568AB26611",
    "reminderMinutesBeforeStart": 15,
    "isReminderOn": true,
    "hasAttachments": false,
    "subject": "Coffee",
    "bodyPreview": "",
    "importance": "normal",
    "sensitivity": "normal",
    "isAllDay": false,
    "isCancelled": false,
    "isOrganizer": true,
    "responseRequested": true,
    "seriesMasterId": null,
    "showAs": "busy",
    "type": "singleInstance",
    "webLink": ...,
    "onlineMeetingUrl": null,
    "responseStatus": {
        "response": "organizer",
        "time": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z"
    },
    "body": {
        "contentType": "html",
        "content": "<html><head><meta name=\"Generator\" content=\"Microsoft Exchange Server\">\r\n<!-- converted from text -->\r\n<style><!-- .EmailQuote { margin-left: 1pt; padding-left: 4pt; border-left: #800000 2px solid; } --></style></head>\r\n<body>\r\n<font size=\"2\"><span style=\"font-size:10pt;\"><div class=\"PlainText\">&nbsp;</div></span></font>\r\n</body>\r\n</html>\r\n"
    },
    "start": {
        "dateTime": "2017-09-29T16:00:00.0000000",
        "timeZone": "Eastern Standard Time"
    },
    "end": {
        "dateTime": "2017-09-29T16:30:00.0000000",
        "timeZone": "Eastern Standard Time"
    },
    "location": {
        "displayName": "Caf\ufffd"
    },
    "recurrence": null,
    "attendees": [{
        "type": "required",
        "status": {
            "response": "none",
            "time": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z"
        },
        "emailAddress": {
            "name": "Betty Kennedy",
            "address": ...
        }
    }],
    "organizer": {
        "emailAddress": {
            "name": ...,
            "address": ...
        }
    },
    "id": "AAMkAGJmNjFhYjM1LTdlsddsa...",
    "id": "AAMkAGJmNjFhYjM1LTdlsddsa..."
},
{
    "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.event",
    "@odata.etag": ...,
    "createdDateTime": "2017-09-29T02:43:31.5152988Z",
    "lastModifiedDateTime": "2017-09-29T02:43:32.1559359Z",
    "changeKey": ...,
    "categories": [],
    "originalStartTimeZone": "UTC",
    "originalEndTimeZone": "UTC",
    "iCalUId": ...,
    "reminderMinutesBeforeStart": 15,
    "isReminderOn": true,
    "hasAttachments": false,
    "subject": "Dinner",
    "bodyPreview": "",
    "importance": "normal",
    "sensitivity": "normal",
    "isAllDay": false,
    "isCancelled": false,
    "isOrganizer": true,
    "responseRequested": true,
    "seriesMasterId": null,
    "showAs": "busy",
    "type": "singleInstance",
    "webLink": ...,
    "onlineMeetingUrl": null,
    "responseStatus": {
        "response": "organizer",
        "time": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z"
    },
    "body": {
        "contentType": "html",
        "content": "<html><head><meta name=\"Generator\" content=\"Microsoft Exchange Server\">\r\n<!-- converted from text -->\r\n<style><!-- .EmailQuote { margin-left: 1pt; padding-left: 4pt; border-left: #800000 2px solid; } --></style></head>\r\n<body>\r\n<font size=\"2\"><span style=\"font-size:10pt;\"><div class=\"PlainText\">&nbsp;</div></span></font>\r\n</body>\r\n</html>\r\n"
    },
    "start": {
        "dateTime": "2017-09-29T19:00:00.0000000",
        "timeZone": "Eastern Standard Time"
    },
    "end": {
        "dateTime": "2017-09-29T20:00:00.0000000",
        "timeZone": "Eastern Standard Time"
    },
    "location": {
        "displayName": "Caf\ufffd"
    },
    "recurrence": null,
    "attendees": [{
        "type": "required",
        "status": {
            "response": "none",
            "time": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z"
        },
        "emailAddress": {
            "name": "Jack Allen",
            "address": ...
        }
    }],
    "organizer": {
        "emailAddress": {
            "name": "xxxxx",
            "address": "xxxx@xxxx.com"
        }
    },
    "id": "AAMkAGJmNjFhYjdfsfsf...",
    "id": "AAMkAGJmNjFhYjdfsfsf..."
}]
```

}

Any idea why I am getting "id" key twice?

Comment: are you still experiencing the same issue? Could you provide a request id?